# How to transpose this dataframe including time by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

### Raw dataframe:

```
   id          time       event city
    A   2016/12/1   3:25     X    M
    A   2016/12/1   9:03     X    M
    A    2016/1/2   9:03     X    M
    A  2016/12/12   9:05     Y    M
    A    2016/1/1   9:34     Z    M
    B   2016/12/1   9:36     X    N
    B   2016/12/2  12:18     Y    N
    B   2016/12/2  12:58     X    N
```

### The transposed dataframe I want

```
id  X_num   X_day   Y_num   Y_day   Z_num   Z_day   X_Dec_day   city
A     3       2       1       1       1       1        1         M
B     2       2       1       1       0       0        2         N
```

### Details:

- id: user
- X_num: calculate X frequency in 2016 for a user (same as Y_num, Z_num)
- X_day: for event X, calculate how many days a user has spent in 2016 (same as Y_day, Z_day)
- X_Dec_day: for event X, calculate how many days a user has spent in December 2016
- city: a user live only in a city(notes: raw data has been checked.)

### Hope:

How can I use pandas to get the result?

Comment: You shouldn't simply ask how to do one thing, you should attempt a solution and ask why it's not working. A few pointers. 1) You probably want to start by doing a `groupby` by `id`, `event`, and `city`, then `count`. You'll get a dataframe with the `_num` data you want, which then you can transpose using `pd.pivot_table`. 2) For the `_day` and `_Dec_day` thing, the `time` column has to be some sort of `datetime` format. Then you can write a custom aggregation function for the `groupby`.